# TFS Build Error While Invoking custom build file via TFS Build definition

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I use TFS 2010, VS 2010.

I wrote a custom msbuild proj file which I use locally to build my solution. I use **MSBUILD.exe TFSBuild.proj** and it does everything in my local machine. (I have a taregt called 'DoMyBuild' which kicks off the build and does everything.)
I have used this in the **DefaultTargets** attribute as below:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="DoMyBuild" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">
```

I am trying hard to configure this to use my build server with a build definition. In the build definition, under Process - I configured 'Upgrade Template' and in the build process paramters, have given the path to this TFSBuild.Proj file.

Ideally. TFS should start 'DoMyBuild' target as I read. But it gives a error looking for 'EndToEndIteration' not defined. So, I believe it is still doing a DesktopBuild which I dont want. I want to use my custom target to kick start. Is this possible ?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks, Mani

Comment: Why do you set ToolsVersion to 3.5, when you are using VS2010? If you want to build like VS2010, you should use 4.0.

Comment: not quite getting it. can u pls explain what do you mean by build like VS2010. To be clear, am using team explorer in vs2010 to create a new build definition where I specify my TFSBuild.proj.

Comment: If ToolsVersion is set to 3.5 it's like building in VS2008. If it is set to 4.0 it's like building in VS2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is discussed [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/969f34e9-3c48-4262-a369-81f9b88ce3cd).

Make sure you have at least an EndToEndIteration target defined in your MSBuild project.

```
<Target Name="EndToEndIteration"
Condition=" '$(IsDesktopBuild)'!='true' "
DependsOnTargets="$(EndToEndIterationDependsOn)" />
```

Comment: So, should I import Import  this namespace as well ?Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets" />

Comment: Please follow the complete post I send the link to. It also has a complete working example.